# I wanna read data from txt file but file_get_contents refuses to read uaing Array so how can i read it my code is here

Tags: php

I am using an HTML form to upload files. Then I use files array to convert them to variable then I am trying to read this variable.

My code is here :

```php
if(isset($_POST['upload'])) {
    $image = $_FILES['sfile'];
    $contents = file_get_contents($image);
    $links = explode(',',$contents);
    echo $links[0];
}
```

Its called from the following form

```html
<html> 
  <head> 
    <title> Trial </title> 
  </head> 
  <body> 
    <form align="center" method="post" action="example.php" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
      Upload File Here : <input type="file" name="sfile"><br> 
      <input type="submit" name ="upload" value="Upload"> 
    </form> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Care to show the inputs to the code, like what $_FILES['sfile'] is?

And what any outputs/errors are?

Comment: <html>
<head>
<title> Trial </title>
</head>
<body>
<form align="center" method="post" action="example.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Upload File Here : <input type="file" name="sfile"><br>
<input type="submit" name ="upload" value="Upload">
</form> </body> </html>

Comment: Output says that file_get_contents  needs a File Name Instead Of Array

Comment: You need to use $_FILES['sfile']['tmp_name']

Comment: That statement in the error message is completely correct. `$_FILES['sfile']` is an _array_ not a string as required by the function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php `$_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']` is what you are looking for, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You should read it from `tmp_name`, see the code below:

```
if (!empty($_FILES['sfile'])) {
    $sfile = $_FILES['sfile'];
    if ($sfile['error'] != UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        // output error here
    } else {
        $contents = file_get_contents($sfile['tmp_name']);
        $links = explode(',', $contents);
        echo $links[0];
    }
}
```

The `$_FILES` has this array format:

```
$_FILES['myfile']['name'] - the original file name
$_FILES['myfile']['type'] - the mime type
$_FILES['myfile']['size'] - the file size
$_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'] - temporary filename
$_FILES['myfile']['error'] - error code
```

Error codes, from http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php:

> UPLOAD_ERR_OK
>   Value: 0; There is no error, the file uploaded with success.
>
> UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE Value: 1; The uploaded file exceeds the
>   upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.
>
> UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE Value: 2; The uploaded file exceeds the
>   MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form.
>
> UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL Value: 3; The uploaded file was only partially
>   uploaded.
>
> UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE Value: 4; No file was uploaded.
>
> UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR Value: 6; Missing a temporary folder. Introduced
>   in PHP 5.0.3.
>
> UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE Value: 7; Failed to write file to disk.
>   Introduced in PHP 5.1.0.
>
> UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION Value: 8; A PHP extension stopped the file
>   upload. PHP does not provide a way to ascertain which extension caused
>   the file upload to stop; examining the list of loaded extensions with
>   phpinfo() may help. Introduced in PHP 5.2.0.

Comment: Thanks ☺ this is what i was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Where you declare $image, it should be `$_FILES['sfile']['tmp_name'];`

> The temporary filename of the file in which the uploaded file was stored on the server.